# Binding information field when adding a new net.pipe binding

Tags: wcf, iis, netnamedpipebinding, net.pipe

What's the use of the binding information field when adding a new net.pipe binding in IIS? I've been told to enter a * in it, but I want to know what it's used for.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the field can be used to enter a domain name, for example if you enter:

```
mysubdomain.mydomain.com
```

Then you can place this in the address of your endpoint in the client config:

```
net.pipe://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/MyService.svc
```

Comment: Thanks - that sorted some IIS routing issues for me :)